# Split a string with two consecutive delimiters in Bash

Tags: bash, split, delimiter

Here is an extract of a Windows DHCP lease file:

```
10.11.1.3       Infinite    DHCP    5c497d1ee201        xxxx    yyyyy
10.11.1.4   PC-name Infinite    DHCP    0002025e611e        xxxx    yyyyy
```

I would like to get IP and MAC in variable. So here is how i parse each line:

```
 IFS=$'\t' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
 ip=${array[0]}
 mac=${array[3]}
```

Problem is that on the first line there is no name, so I have two consecutive tab between IP and infinite. So with this code, the first line is parsed correctly, but on the second line, I get "DHCP" in variable mac.

How should I correct that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `awk` with tab as input field separator:

```sh
awk -F '\t' '{print $1, $5}' file

10.11.1.3 5c497d1ee201
10.11.1.4 0002025e611e
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `readarray` instead.

```
$ line=$'10.11.1.3\t\tInfinite\tDHCP\t5c497d1ee201\txxxx\tyyyyy'
$ readarray -d $'\t' -t array <<< "$line"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="10.11.1.3" [1]="" [2]="Infinite" [3]="DHCP" [4]="5c497d1ee201" [5]="xxxx" [6]=$'yyyyy\n')
```

If the trailing line break is a problem, either manually trim it, or append a tab to input and limit it out.

```
$ readarray -d $'\t' -t -n 7 array <<< "$line"$'\t'
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="10.11.1.3" [1]="" [2]="Infinite" [3]="DHCP" [4]="5c497d1ee201" [5]="xxxx" [6]="yyyyy")
```